# Vue+Firebase Conditional Rendering

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I'm working through the Vue + Firebase. Each data on firebase, have `isFinished: false/true` statement. And I want to print isFinished: false datas. How can i print them with v-for? This is my code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in works" :key="index.id" class="list-table">
      <td id="checkbox-td" style="width: 24px">
        <span class="list-checkbox" @click="clickCheckbox(index, item)"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        {{item.name}}
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">
        {{item.username}}<br>
        <span style="font-size:10px;">{{item.date}} {{item.hour}}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap item with `template` and add `v-for` onto it:

```
  <tbody>
     <template v-for="(item, index) in works" :key="index.id">
    <tr  class="list-table" v-if="!item.isFinished">
      <td id="checkbox-td" style="width: 24px">
        <span class="list-checkbox" @click="clickCheckbox(index, item)"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        {{item.name}}
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">
        {{item.username}}<br>
        <span style="font-size:10px;">{{item.date}} {{item.hour}}</span>
      </td>
  </tr>
  </template>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score -1):

```
<th>Finished</th>
<tbody> 
<tr v-for="(item, index) in works" :key="index.id" class="list-table">
<td data-label="Finished">{{item.isFinished? 'Finished' : 'Not Finished'}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Add this to Your Table!

Comment: It's working but I don't want this. I want to If isFinished equal false return data, but not false skip this data and don't print that one.